# About the Fourier and cosine Fourier Transforms

Tags: fourier-transform

A known result on Fourier analysis states that if $f$ and its Fourier transform are in $C_0^{\infty}(\mathbb R)$, then $f$ must vanish. This may also be regarded as a special case of a result by Hardy.

My question is: Does anyone know whether a similar result holds if $f$ and its cosine Fourier transform are in $C_0^{\infty}(\mathbb R)$, then must $f$ vanish?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I don't know much about this topic but I guess that it could be that the real part and imaginary part vanish, respectively (?)

Comment: Thanks Gonzalo Benavides.but in my case, I only have t$f$ and its cosine Fourier transform in $C_0^{\infty}(\mathbb R)$ and I would like $f=0$.

Comment: This is an 'uncertainty principle'. What do you mean by $C_0^\infty$? The Fourier transform of a Gaussian is a Gaussian.

Comment: Yes, this is the space of $C^{\infty}$ functions with compact support...

Comment: Why would the cosine series be any different? It is the Fourier transform of an even function.

Comment: I am somehow not following you copper.hat. Is the answer yes to my question?

Comment: The cosine Fourier series is a special case of the Fourier transform, so the result must still be true.

Comment: Hopefully this is true but I still don't see it as straightforward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that any odd function $f$  (i.e. such that $\forall t\in\mathbb{R}, f(-t)=-f(t)$) that is also in $C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R})\backslash \{0\}$ is a counterexample. In fact, if $f$ is such a function (and there are a lot of these functions), then: $$\forall\xi\in\mathbb{R}, \int_{\mathbb{R}}f(t)\cos({2\pi t\xi})\operatorname{d}t=\int_0^{\infty}f(t)\cos({2\pi t\xi})\operatorname{d}t+\int_{-\infty}^0f(t)\cos({2\pi t\xi})\operatorname{d}t=\\=\int_0^{\infty}f(t)\cos({2\pi t\xi})\operatorname{d}t-\int_{-\infty}^0f(-t)\cos({2\pi t\xi})\operatorname{d}t\\=\int_0^{\infty}f(t)\cos({2\pi t\xi})\operatorname{d}t-\int_{0}^{\infty}f(t)\cos({-2\pi t\xi})\operatorname{d}t\\=\int_0^{\infty}f(t)\cos({2\pi t\xi})\operatorname{d}t-\int_{0}^{\infty}f(t)\cos({2\pi t\xi})\operatorname{d}t=0.$$
so $f$ has a vanishing cosine Fourier transform, so in particular is in $C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R})$, but $f$ is not the null function.

However, you can recover a positive result if you require that your function is even. In fact, in this case, its sine Fourier transform identically vanish (with a similar argument as before) and by requiring that the cosine Fourier transform is an element of $C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R})$, from: $$\forall \xi\in\mathbb{R},\hat{f}(\xi)=\int_\mathbb{R}f(t)e^{-2\pi i\xi t}\operatorname{d}t=\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(t)\cos(-{2\pi t\xi})\operatorname{d}t+i\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(t)\sin({-2\pi t\xi})\operatorname{d}t\\=\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(t)\cos({2\pi t\xi})\operatorname{d}t,$$
you get that $\hat{f}\in C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R})$ and you can apply the result you quoted in your question.

Comment: Great answer but unfortunately for me it destroys an idea I wanted to develop. Maybe I can adapt the even case to get something interesting. Thanks a lot Bob

Comment: In particular, is the space of even functions which are infinitely differentiable with compact support also dense in $L^2(\mathbb R)$? Thanks a lot Bob

Comment: No, they are dense in "even" $L^2$. Here you may have some trouble in defining what "even" means by the fact that an $L^2$ element only identify the values of a function almost everywhere. You can get rid of this difficulty defining "even" $L^2$ as the kernel of sine Fourier transform

Comment: You may also define $T:L^2\rightarrow L^2,f\mapsto(x\mapsto f(-x))$, check that T is well defined and continuous, and say that $f\in L^2$ is even if $\frac{I+T}{2}(f)=f$. Obviously the two given definitions coincide.

Comment: Thanks again Bob.